# Chainage points along 3D polyline preserving elevation

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qchainage

How can I extract chainage points along 3D polylines doing a full 3D interpolation of the point along the line?

For example, returning a pointZ shapefile where the elevation of each point along the line is calculated.  Each line vertex has a different, random elevation.

In QGIS, I have used the plugin QChainage in the past and it works great.  I use it frequently, but it only seems to produce 2D datasets - the 3D info seems to be discarded in the output.

To be clear, I'm not trying to modify the way the chainage distance is calculated in QChainage. 2D calculation of distance is fine for point spacing.